# How to have normal speed of output video in my Dense Optical Flow model?

Tags: opencv, video, opticalflow

My code below is from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html, idk why the output video is so slow, how to change back to normal speed guys?

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture('NY.avi')
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
prvs = cv.cvtColor(frame1,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
hsv[...,1] = 255
while(1):
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    next = cv.cvtColor(frame2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flow = cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    mag, ang = cv.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])
    hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi/2
    hsv[...,2] = cv.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv.NORM_MINMAX)
    bgr = cv.cvtColor(hsv,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv.imshow('frame2',bgr)
    k = cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        cv.imwrite('opticalfb.png',frame2)
        cv.imwrite('opticalhsv.png',bgr)
    prvs = next
```

Comment: you mean the shown output on the screen (image window)? That's slow because your machine isnt fast enough to compute a dense optical flow + image writing + 30 ms waiting in your desired time/speed.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you

Comment: if you want to record it to a video file you can use cv.VideoWriter where you have to specify the fps. You can read the original fps from the VideoCapture object.